# Earnest and serious: when should each be used?

Tags: word-choice, words

I've noticed there's a lot of overlap between the following words meaning "earnest" or "serious" when talking about a person:

- まじ
- 真面目{まじめ}
- 真剣{しんけん}
- 本気{ほんき}
- 正気{しょうき}: (This word really means "sane" I believe, but I'm including it as I think 「正気か？」 can translate to "are you serious?")
- 素直{すなお}: (I'm not sure whether this word meaning "honest" belongs here I but keep wondering what it's relationship to 真面目{まじめ} is when it means "obedient". I thought there might be some overlap in it's usage, e.g. 「素直な顔」 "obedient face" and 「真面目な顔」 "serious face". It could well be unrelated though.)

Would I be allowed to ask what the differences between these words are and when they're used?

Comment: This may not be directly relevant but I think it's good to appreciate/consider what 真面目[zhēnmiànmù] means in Chinese. It's means the "true colours(or features)" of a person/thing (More literally translated as the "true face" of a person/thing).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- `まじ` colloquial and contracted form of `真面目`.
- `真面目` 'diligent, serious'
- `真剣` 'serious, under one's best' implies some tension
- `本気` 'one's best, mean it'
- `正気` 'has not lost conscious (due to alchohol, drug, fainting, or extreme situation, etc.)'
- `素直` 'obedient, open minded'

Comment: Somehow まじ often takes で instead of に, so its usage is different from 真面目 even ignoring the difference in formality.

Answer (score 3):

> まじ

Never heard it used, except in
「まじで？」 which is sometimes written "本気".
It means "aren't you joking" (see 本気)

> 真面目

真面目に勉強した。
He applied himself to studying.

> 真剣

真剣にやってくだい。
Do it conscientiously, won't you?

> 本気

本気で言った。
He wasn't joking when he said that.

> 正気

I never heard/used it enough to answer…

> 素直

Unrelated to the above… It means docile, honest, compliant…

Comment: `まじ` is not only used in questions. Your description about it is too limited.